# Auto mount USB drive with permissions for all users

Tags: mount, permissions

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 based Media Center and I store the media files on a USB HDD.  I add files to drive directly on a Mac so I have it formatted as FAT32.

The problem is that after reconnecting the drive to the Ubuntu, it mounts at `/media/user/drivename` and only the root user is allowed access.  I need several applications to have full access to this drive.  I can change file permissions in the terminal but it doesn't change because of the `/media/user` location.  I am able to manually `sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/drivename` & `sudo chmod 777 /media/drivename` but the mount point changes each time.

Is there a way to make this drive always mount where root and other applications have access?

Comment: Connect the USB disk, and so `sudo blkid`. It should give you the UUIDs of all the partitions. From there we can build a correct entry for `/etc/fstab`. Edit the question to add the output.

Comment: Found the UUID but not exactly sure how to build the correct fstab entry

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the UUID, you can edit `/etc/fstab` and add an entry like so:

```
UUID=<the UUID> /media/drivename vfat rw,nofail,umask=022,uid=<UID>,gid=<GID> 0 0
```

Replace `<UID>` and `<GID>` with the output of `id -u` and `id -g` respectively.

Explanation:

1. We need the UUID since the drive is a removable one, and we can't rely on `/dev/sdXY` as an identifier.
2. `vfat` is the mount type for FAT32 systems
3. The `nofail` option should prevent mount from complaining, or your boot from being held up, if the disk is not present.
4. The `uid=<UID>,gid=<GID>` options set the ownership of all files and folders in the mounted disk, since FAT32 doesn't have a Unix-like permission/ownership structure. This doesn't affect the files themselves, only the mounted representation. Ditto for the `umask`.