# Other users cannot accesss External Drive

Tags: mount, external-hdd

I am running Ubuntu on a laptop, version 18.04.4 LTS. I connected an external drive to the computer and the user that is logged in when I connect the drive is able to access the drive. When other users log and try to access the drive they get this message, "You do not have the permissions necessesary to view the contents of "'External'"

If one of the other users mounts the external drive then they are able to access the drive but not the other users. One other thing, the drive is formatted in NTFS. I would like to have all users able to access the drive.

Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong and how to fix it.

Edit: I did find this one [Solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515600/auto-mount-usb-drive-with-permissions-for-all-users) but I'm unsure if the vfat command would apply to my ntfs drive.

Comment: This is a safety feature. Try plugging in the drive when the computer is turned off, and then turn the computer on and login.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto mount USB drive with permissions for all users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515600/auto-mount-usb-drive-with-permissions-for-all-users)