# Auto full permission for subfolder when plug in the usb

Tags: usb, permissions

i have a player that auto download the files if i plug in usb, for some pc its working smoothly but i got problem for some pc with same OS ( ubuntu ) but different type and i test to give full permission access ( 777 ) to the files manually with chmod and its working

try to edit fstab  but the usb uuid not shown :

```
UUID=C0C2-706F                            /boot/efi      vfat    umask=0077 0 2
UUID=d2187334-fc44-48c1-9226-f23f6289d985 /              ext4    defaults   0 1
```

result for the mount :

```
/dev/sda2 on /media/amg/TO1 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1001,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,ioc            harset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
```

result for lsb_release -
a;uname -a :

```
amg@amg:~$ lsb_release -a;uname -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
Linux amg 5.11.0-27-generic #29~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 11 15:58:17 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

result for lsblk ( usb at sda2 ):

```
amg@amg:~$ lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda            8:0    1  7,3G  0 disk
├─sda1         8:1    1  200M  0 part
└─sda2         8:2    1  7,1G  0 part /media/amg/TO1
mmcblk0      179:0    0 29,1G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1  179:1    0  300M  0 part /boot/efi
└─mmcblk0p2  179:2    0 28,8G  0 part /
mmcblk0boot0 179:8    0    4M  1 disk
mmcblk0boot1 179:16   0    4M  1 disk
```

result for lsblk -e7 -o model,name,size,fstype,uuid :

```
amg@amg:~$ lsblk -e7 -o model,name,size,fstype,uuid
MODEL        NAME          SIZE FSTYPE UUID
Cruzer_Blade sda           7,3G
             ├─sda1        200M vfat   67E3-17ED
             └─sda2        7,1G vfat   D078-0D63
             mmcblk0      29,1G
             ├─mmcblk0p1   300M vfat   C0C2-706F
             └─mmcblk0p2  28,8G ext4   d2187334-fc44-48c1-9226-f23f6289d985
             mmcblk0boot0    4M
             mmcblk0boot1    4M
```

my question is how to make the subfolder file get auto full permission when i plug in the usb ?

thanks

Comment: Does the option `nofail` help ?

Comment: `chown -R username ./yourfolder`

Comment: nope, the OS still stuck @Marco

Comment: its working if i grant it manually chown/chmod, but i want it auto grant when i plug in the usb @TalaatEtman

Comment: Unless you [edit] your Question and show us the actual `/etc/fstab` line, the results of the `mount` command, and the results of `lsb_release -a;uname -a`, we don't know enough to help.

Comment: according to the manuals, exfat can only be used with fuse. Means exfat can not be used in `/etc/fstab`

Comment: see this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/515605/1698042

Comment: already edited, but now my usb ( vfat/exvat) not shown the uuid @waltinator

Comment: vfat/exvat is not detailed enough. Is it FAT32 or exFAT or something else? Anyway, a Microsoft filesystem must be treated in one way and a Linux filesystem for example `ext4` in another way. You can run the command line `lsblk -e7 -o model,name,size,fstype,uuid` in order to find out, if you are not sure.

Comment: im try to used FAT32 & exFAT but the uuid not shown in fstab, already edited, the result for lsblk -e7 -o model,name,size,fstype,uuid @sudodus

Answer (score 0):

It should work to mount the partition in the USB drive after editing the following line into `/etc/fstab` (assuming access for the first user (with uid=1000). Open the file in a text editor

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

add one of the following lines and finally save the edited file with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> (and **`y`** for yes).

- alternative 1, drive always to be plugged in (and automatically mounted at boot),

  ```
  UUID=D078-0D63  /mnt/usbdata  vfat  rw,user,uid=1000,dmask=007,fmask=117  0  0
  ```
- alternative 2, drive to be plugged in when computer is running,

  ```
  UUID=D078-0D63  /mnt/usbdata  vfat  noauto,rw,user,uid=1000,dmask=007,fmask=117  0  0
  ```

  Here you must also mount the file system by

  ```
  sudo mount /mnt/usbdata
  ```
- creating a mountpoint

  ```
  sudo mkdir /mnt/usbdata
  ```
- and rebooting.

---

- If you format the drive, the UUID will change and you can use

  ```
  lsblk -e7 -o model,name,size,fstype,uuid
  ```

  to find the new UUID.
- If you want to modify the permissions, see [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072).
- If still no luck mounting the file system in the USB drive, the best tip I can think of is that Windows has left the drive 'dirty', and you can try to repair it with Windows tools.

  This can be avoided if you turn off fast startup in Windows, and always use safe removal of the drive (flush the buffers so that the write operations reach the memory cells before you unplug the drive). In Ubuntu you can do that with the command

  ```
  sync
  ```

  or 'eject' in the graphical interface. A safe way to `sync` and prevent further writes is to unmount,

  ```
  sudo umount /mnt/usbdata
  ```

Comment: i got error when try run the first line command :
amg@amg:/media/amg/TO1$ lsblk -e7 -o model,name,size,fstype,uuid                                     MODEL        NAME          SIZE FSTYPE UUID
Cruzer_Blade sda           7,3G
             └─sda1        7,3G vfat   7C10-C25D
amg@amg:/media/amg/TO1$ UUID=7C10-C25D  /mnt/media/amg/TO1/  vfat  rw,user,uid=1000,dmask=007,fmask=117  0  0
-bash: /mnt/media/amg/TO1/: No such file or directory

Comment: It is very difficult to read the output of the lsblk command in a comment, because it is 'unformatted'. Please edit your original question to enter the command and its output and render it as `code` by indenting each line four spaces (or use the relevant button at the top of the editing window).

Comment: The first code line is not a command, I meant that you should open the file `/etc/fstab` in a text editor and add that line: `sudo nano /etc/fstab`; add that line and finally save the edited file.